# High school mathematics Area problem

Tags: geometry

Please help me out here, as I am unable to solve this question and could you please show your working out.Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you find the radius of circle?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know that, in order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Related: [How to calculate the radius of a circle inside a hexagon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766870/how-to-calculate-the-radius-of-a-circle-inside-a-hexagon), [Number of square units in area of regular hexagon with unit circle inscribed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339007/number-of-square-units-in-area-of-regular-hexagon-with-unit-circle-inscribed).

Answer (score 3):

I'll give some tips, first use that this hexagon is regular, and divide it in six equilateral triangles, then just look the relation between the height of these triangles and the radius of the circle.

Comment: Thank you, I had got the answer 8.71 but,I was wondering if that was the correct answer

Comment: @DoviBerman  What the "correct" answer is shouldn't concern you that much. We are interested in seeing what you do to arrive at the result. If your reasoning is correct and you compute correctly, you will arrive at correct result, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The circle area equals $6^2×π=36π$ cm.

This hexagon consists of 6 congruent triangles; thus, each area equals:

$0.5×6×6×\sqrt{3}×0.5=9\sqrt{3}$  cm$^2$.

Therefore, the area of the whole hexagon is $54\sqrt{3}$ cm$^2$.

Hence the shaded area is $54\sqrt{3}-36π$ cm$^2$.

Comment: you know you can use MathJaX for all of this right ?

Comment: an area measured in cm is quite weird  :P